# Calculate column median absolute deviation (MAD) by column for each dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I want to calculate the Median absolute deviation (mscore) by column ignoring the first column for each dataframe in a list of dataframes.  Then add the result as a new row into the dataframe with the row name mscore.

Previously I would do the calculation on each dataframe one at a time but now its streamline the process.

A small extract of my list of dataframes below.  The full list of dfs has over 30 dataframes

```r
   list(Al2O3 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(2.01, 
    2.02, 2.03, 2.01, 2.02, 2), `3` = c(2.01, 2.01, 2, 2.02, 2.02, 
    2.03), `4` = c(2, 2.03, 1.99, 2.01, 2.01, 2.01), `5` = c(2.02, 
    2.02, 2.05, 2.03, 2.02, 2.03), `7` = c(1.88, 1.9, 1.89, 1.88, 
    1.88, 1.87), `8` = c(2.053, 2.044, 2.041, 2.038, 2.008, 2.02), 
    `10` = c(2.002830415, 2.021725042, 2.021725042, 1.983935789, 
    2.002830415, 2.021725042), `12` = c(2.09, 2.05, 1.96, 2.09, 
    2.06, 2.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
    )), As = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(0.052, 
    0.027, 0.011, 0.011, 0.012, 0.012), `3` = c(0.012, 0.012, 0.013, 
    0.012, 0.013, 0.013), `4` = c(0.012, 0.012, 0.013, 0.012, 0.012, 
    0.012), `5` = c(0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013, 0.013), `7` = c(0.011, 
    0.011, 0.011, 0.012, 0.011, 0.011), `8` = c(0.011, 0.01, 0.011, 
    0.011, 0.011, 0.011), `10` = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
    0.01), `12` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), Fe = structure(list(
    Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(55.94, 55.7, 56.59, 56.5, 
    55.98, 55.93), `3` = c(56.83, 56.54, 56.18, 56.5, 56.51, 
    56.34), `4` = c(56.39, 56.43, 56.53, 56.31, 56.47, 56.35), 
    `5` = c(56.32, 56.29, 56.31, 56.32, 56.39, 56.32), `7` = c(56.48, 
    56.4, 56.54, 56.43, 56.73, 56.62), `8` = c(56.382, 56.258, 
    56.442, 56.258, 56.532, 56.264), `10` = c(56.3, 56.5, 56.2, 
    56.5, 56.7, 56.5), `12` = c(56.11, 56.46, 56.1, 56.35, 56.36, 
    56.37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)))
```

Previously I would do the following

```r
#create a modified scores function to accept NAs

scores_na <- function(x, ...) { 
  not_na <- !is.na(x)
  scores <- rep(NA, length(x))
  scores[not_na] <- outliers::scores(na.omit(x), ...)
  scores
}

MscoreMax <- 3.0 # the the threshold to remove values deemed to be an outlier

 colmedians <- median, df[-1], na.rm = T)
 MScore <- as.vector(round(abs(scores_na(colmedians, "mad")), digits = 2)) #Mscore to 2 decimals 
places
 MscoreIndex <- which(MScore > MscoreMax) #get the index of each value exceeding the threshold
 df[-1][Fe.MscoreIndex] <- NA # change outliers to NA so they are excluded from further calculations
```

I have tried the line below to calculate the median

the colmedians function is for a matrix so I have used mapply to apply across the columns

```r
df <- lapply(df, function(x) rbind(x[,-1], 
                                   mapply(median(x[,-1],na.rm = TRUE))))
```

however I get the follow error

```
    Error in median.default(x[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) : need numeric data
```

when I query the dataframes i the values are stored as double so a bit stuck.

Comment: FYI, code blocks are delimited by code fences, which are three *backticks* (`\`\`\``), not single-quotes as you have here; see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: @r2evans apologies

Comment: no need for apologies! I was just advising on question formatting. If it was pushy, I apologize, I can rollback.

Comment: @r2evans no you were not.  The feedback and edits are useful. I am looking for help so the easier for everyone the better

Comment: The use of `mapply` is wrong here, but that can easily be remedied (the first arguments need to be a function, not the result of a function call, but I'm not convinced you need `mapply`, `lapply` should work). However ... rbinding a row and adding a row-name is one thing, but row-names can be easily lost. I'm usually not a fan of adding a summary-statistic as a *row* to the actual data, is rbinding the row solely for presentation/rendering in a report?

Comment: @r2evans.  I am not hung up on any one approach and writing functions is my weak spot so I tend to find a work around.  I used mapply as originally it was being applied to one df and was creating a vector.   Yes the intent is to slowly build up for presentation in a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
lapply(A, function(x) {x[nrow(x) + 1,] <- apply(x, 2, function(y) median(y, na.rm = TRUE)); 
                  x <- x[,-1]; 
                  rownames(x)[nrow(x)] <- "mscores"; 
                          return(x)})
```

Then we get the result

```
    > lapply(A, function(x) {x[nrow(x) + 1,] <- apply(x, 2, function(y) median(y, na.rm = TRUE)); x <- x[,-1]; rownames(x)[nrow(x)] <- "mscores"; return(x)})
$Al2O3
            2     3    4     5    7      8       10    12
1       2.010 2.010 2.00 2.020 1.88 2.0530 2.002830 2.090
2       2.020 2.010 2.03 2.020 1.90 2.0440 2.021725 2.050
3       2.030 2.000 1.99 2.050 1.89 2.0410 2.021725 1.960
4       2.010 2.020 2.01 2.030 1.88 2.0380 1.983936 2.090
5       2.020 2.020 2.01 2.020 1.88 2.0080 2.002830 2.060
6       2.000 2.030 2.01 2.030 1.87 2.0200 2.021725 2.020
mscores 2.015 2.015 2.01 2.025 1.88 2.0395 2.012278 2.055

$As
            2      3     4     5     7     8   10 12
1       0.052 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
2       0.027 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.010 0.01 NA
3       0.011 0.0130 0.013 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
4       0.011 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.012 0.011 0.01 NA
5       0.012 0.0130 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
6       0.012 0.0130 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
mscores 0.012 0.0125 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA

$Fe
            2      3     4     5     7      8   10     12
1       55.94 56.830 56.39 56.32 56.48 56.382 56.3 56.110
2       55.70 56.540 56.43 56.29 56.40 56.258 56.5 56.460
3       56.59 56.180 56.53 56.31 56.54 56.442 56.2 56.100
4       56.50 56.500 56.31 56.32 56.43 56.258 56.5 56.350
5       55.98 56.510 56.47 56.39 56.73 56.532 56.7 56.360
6       55.93 56.340 56.35 56.32 56.62 56.264 56.5 56.370
mscores 55.96 56.505 56.41 56.32 56.51 56.323 56.5 56.355
```

Comment: thanks. your solution calculates the median and allows me to assign the row name so that is a big help

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your question, you may indicate that by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: unfortunately it is only half the answer I need

Comment: What else do you need beside the median for each data.frame and the deletion of the first column? You may update your initial question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to apply a function to all or some columns in a `data.frame` is `lapply`, by far.

I don't think `mapply` is useful in your use there: its first argument needs to be a `function`, unevaluated, not an evaluated expression as in `median(.)`. I think, though, that we can use `lapply` instead.

> FYI, these two calls are an equivalency between `mapply` and `lapply`:
>
> ```r
> lapply(list(1:2, 3:4), sum)
> mapply(sum, list(1:2, 3:4))
> ```
>
> However, only `mapply` can do this directly (`lapply` can do it using indices instead of raw data):
>
> ```r
> mapply(function(x, y) sum(x) + y, list(1:2, 3:4), list(5, 6))
> ```
>
> which "unrolls" into
>
> ```r
> sum(1:2) + 5
> sum(3:4) + 6
> ```

My first step is to aggregate the data, which is pretty straight-forward.

```r
tmp <- lapply(z, function(x) as.data.frame(lapply(x[,-1], median, na.rm=TRUE), check.names = FALSE))
tmp
# $Al2O3
#       2     3    4     5    7      8       10    12
# 1 2.015 2.015 2.01 2.025 1.88 2.0395 2.012278 2.055
# $As
#       2      3     4     5     7     8   10 12
# 1 0.012 0.0125 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# $Fe
#       2      3     4     5     7      8   10     12
# 1 55.96 56.505 56.41 56.32 56.51 56.323 56.5 56.355
```

I could easily have appended this data to the original data and added a row-name, as suggested, but I wanted to briefly discuss against this:

- if you are going to do any more analysis/calculation on the data, I believe that adding summary statistics within the data itself is not a good thing;
- there is no clear guidance on what to do with `Determination_No`;
- row names *can* be fragile; while many R functions use and preserve them fine, some do not ... and most functions from `dplyr` and related packages (if you use them) make no effort to preserve them (occasionally intentionally wiping them);

Ultimately, I suspect that your desire to add it as the last row is for presentation, so is best done (in my head) as part of the rendering process. For instance,

```r
Map(function(nm, dat, smry) {
  dat$Determination_No <- as.character(dat$Determination_No)
  rbind(dat, cbind(data.frame(Determination_No = paste(nm, "median -->")), smry))
}, names(z), z, tmp)
# $Al2O3
#   Determination_No     2     3    4     5    7      8       10    12
# 1                1 2.010 2.010 2.00 2.020 1.88 2.0530 2.002830 2.090
# 2                2 2.020 2.010 2.03 2.020 1.90 2.0440 2.021725 2.050
# 3                3 2.030 2.000 1.99 2.050 1.89 2.0410 2.021725 1.960
# 4                4 2.010 2.020 2.01 2.030 1.88 2.0380 1.983936 2.090
# 5                5 2.020 2.020 2.01 2.020 1.88 2.0080 2.002830 2.060
# 6                6 2.000 2.030 2.01 2.030 1.87 2.0200 2.021725 2.020
# 7 Al2O3 median --> 2.015 2.015 2.01 2.025 1.88 2.0395 2.012278 2.055
# $As
#   Determination_No     2      3     4     5     7     8   10 12
# 1                1 0.052 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# 2                2 0.027 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.010 0.01 NA
# 3                3 0.011 0.0130 0.013 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# 4                4 0.011 0.0120 0.012 0.013 0.012 0.011 0.01 NA
# 5                5 0.012 0.0130 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# 6                6 0.012 0.0130 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# 7    As median --> 0.012 0.0125 0.012 0.013 0.011 0.011 0.01 NA
# $Fe
#   Determination_No     2      3     4     5     7      8   10     12
# 1                1 55.94 56.830 56.39 56.32 56.48 56.382 56.3 56.110
# 2                2 55.70 56.540 56.43 56.29 56.40 56.258 56.5 56.460
# 3                3 56.59 56.180 56.53 56.31 56.54 56.442 56.2 56.100
# 4                4 56.50 56.500 56.31 56.32 56.43 56.258 56.5 56.350
# 5                5 55.98 56.510 56.47 56.39 56.73 56.532 56.7 56.360
# 6                6 55.93 56.340 56.35 56.32 56.62 56.264 56.5 56.370
# 7    Fe median --> 55.96 56.505 56.41 56.32 56.51 56.323 56.5 56.355
```

Even more can be done using table-rendering tools such as `knitr::kable`, the `gt` package, `DT` (if using this in an html environment), and others.